# how to reset key IDs numbering for a table after deleting one row, SQLite database Android

Tags: android, sqlite

If I have a SQLite table where I delete one row in the middle of it,  it removes that row, but the numbering is off.  example, removed row 4

```
 id   name
 1     A
 2     B
 3     C
 5     E
 6     F
```

How can I reset the numbering so that it the key auto incremented key ID is continuous with out the missing 4 like in the table above?

one idea is to delete all the key row ids and re insert them in a for loop.  not sure if I should try that as it is auto increment.  the other possibility is to make it not auto increment, and use loops to put the numbers in when the table is crated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already answered your own question: It's an `AUTOINCREMENT` field, so you can't do that. Furthermore, this is not how ids should be used in SQL anyway. They are to uniquely identify a row, and if you change the id, then you're breaking that, as well as any references there might possibly be to that id.

Comment: You should another add column, e.g. nameID, and work with that.